# Snort rule can not catch a download JPG file from internet

Tags: rules, snort

I am a newbie of Snort. I try to write the snort rule to catch a download JPG file from internet. 
Here is my rule:

```
alert tcp any any <> $HOME_NET any (msg:"JPEG"; content:"|FF D8 FF E0|"; sid:1000001)
```

But it does not work. Can everybody help me to find out the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a rule error? Check 'sid:1000001`;`'

Comment: Sorry, I lack ";" when posting to here, It existed in my rule. The Snort is run successfully in my device. But when I download JPEG from the internet , there is no any alert.

Comment: Try test without `content`. And compare test(with content) to test(without content). It is easy to get an answer if show the log when snort has finished running.

Comment: I tested this case. But when I click to url to download image, there is no package is match with content of JPEG file. It mean the snort does not detect download file. It just detect some verification package.